# Form won't bind to model on POST request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Here is my view:

```
<form asp-action="SaveAssignments">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.CreatedUser" />
    <div class="card m-5">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="container d-md-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h2><label asp-for="Stores" class="form-control-label"></label></h2>
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary text-bold dropdown-toggle">@Model.Stores.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Value == Model.SelectedStoreId.ToString())?.Text<span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Stores)
                        {
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Web" asp-action="Assignments" asp-route-storeId="@item.Value" asp-route-groupId="@Model.SelectedGroupId">@item.Text</a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group align-content-center">
                    <h2><label asp-for="Groups" class="form-control-label"></label></h2>
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary text-bold dropdown-toggle">@Model.Groups.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Value == Model.SelectedGroupId.ToString())?.Text<span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Groups)
                        {
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Web" asp-action="Assignments" asp-route-storeId="@Model.SelectedStoreId" asp-route-groupId="@item.Value">@item.Text</a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group align-self-end">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <h2><label asp-for="ListZoneFrom" class="form-control-label"></label></h2>
                    <select id="from" asp-for="ListZoneFrom" asp-items="Model.ListZoneFrom" size="15" class="form-control" style="width:100%"></select>
                </div>
              
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <h2><label asp-for="ListZoneTo" class="form-control-label"></label></h2>
                    <select id="to" asp-for="SelectedZoneTo" asp-items="Model.ListZoneTo" size="15" class="form-control" style="width:100%"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my model:

```
 public class AssignmentsViewModel
    {
        public AssignmentsViewModel()
        {
            Groups = new List<SelectListItem>();
            ListZoneFrom = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectedZoneTo = new List<int>();
            ListZoneTo = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        public int SelectedStoreId { get; set; }
        public int SelectedGroupId { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Groups { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "From: ")]
        public List<SelectListItem> ListZoneFrom { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "To: ")]
        public List<SelectListItem> ListZoneTo { get; set; }
        public List<int> SelectedZoneTo { get; set; }
        public string CreatedUser { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Stores {get; set;}    
    }
```

When I submit the form (HttpPost), the only parameter that gets bound is CreatedUser, the rest of them are either null or 0. My question is how do I bind the values in List ListZoneTo to List SelectedZoneTo? Everytime I post, I get0 items in that list. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <select id="to" asp-for="SelectedZoneTo" asp-items="Model.ListZoneTo" size="15" class="form-control" style="width:100%"></select>
```

Thanks

Comment: doesn't look like there's anything in those lists.  (did you include the full code?)  The "SelectList" type is used to populate options for traditional select tags.  (<OPTION> inside of <SELECT>)  Then you'd do something like: <select asp-for="Stores"
                                         asp-items="@Model.Stores" </select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your codes, it works fine, I can bind the values in `ListZoneTo` to `SelectedZoneTo`.

The problem may be from your controller action, can you show us the codes?

Below is the test example:

View:

```
@model AssignmentsViewModel

<form asp-action="SaveAssignments" asp-controller="Web">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.CreatedUser" />
    <div class="card m-5">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="container d-md-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h2><label asp-for="Stores" class="form-control-label"></label></h2>
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary text-bold dropdown-toggle">@Model.Stores.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Value == Model.SelectedStoreId.ToString())?.Text<span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Stores)
                        {
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Web" asp-action="Assignments" asp-route-storeId="@item.Value" asp-route-groupId="@Model.SelectedGroupId">@item.Text</a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group align-content-center">
                    <h2><label asp-for="Groups" class="form-control-label"></label></h2>
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary text-bold dropdown-toggle">@Model.Groups.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Value == Model.SelectedGroupId.ToString())?.Text<span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Groups)
                        {
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Web" asp-action="Assignments" asp-route-storeId="@Model.SelectedStoreId" asp-route-groupId="@item.Value">@item.Text</a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group align-self-end">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <h2><label asp-for="ListZoneFrom" class="form-control-label"></label></h2>
                    <select id="from" asp-for="ListZoneFrom" asp-items="Model.ListZoneFrom" size="15" class="form-control" style="width:100%"></select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <h2><label asp-for="ListZoneTo" class="form-control-label"></label></h2>
                    <select id="to" asp-for="SelectedZoneTo" asp-items="Model.ListZoneTo" size="15" class="form-control" style="width:100%"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var listZoneTo = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "AA", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "BB", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "CC", Value = "3"},
    };

    var listZoneFrom = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "aa", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "bb", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "cc", Value = "3"},
    };

    var stores = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Store1", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Store2", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Store3", Value = "3"},
    };

    var groups = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Group1", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Group2", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Group3", Value = "3"},
    };
    var model = new AssignmentsViewModel();
    model.CreatedUser = "ABC";
    model.SelectedStoreId = 1;
    model.SelectedGroupId = 2;
    model.ListZoneFrom = listZoneFrom;
    model.ListZoneTo = listZoneTo;
    model.Groups = groups;
    model.Stores = stores;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveAssignments(AssignmentsViewModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Result:

[image]